# Safe way to fetch data with mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, code-injection

i wrote this code before i was aware of the use of prepared statements and what it does to SQL injections. Now i'm also aware of how messy it is to fetch arrays with prepared statements. So i was wondering if this piece of code is safe to use since it doesn't use any user submitted information to fetch the rows.

What it does is to identify the row in the db table by using a session id, session is ensured by a login_check function etc..:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$select = mysqli_query($link, " SELECT product_id, product_title, product_value                             
                                FROM product
                                WHERE user_id='$username'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select))
{
    $product[] = array(
            'product_id' => $row['product_id'], 
            'product_title' => $row['product_title'], 
            'product_value' => $row['product_value']);
}
```

Some information regarding this issue would really be appreciated since things were going so well until i got to know of the prepared statements..

**Edit**
So, i kinda went in another direction and skipped the array part completely for this query. Instead i went with the prepared statement and did something like this..:

`$select_stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT etc...)`
`$select_stmt->bind_param("CODE")`
`$select_stmt->execute();`
And so on..

But the thing is that my bind_result got pretty big (?) with 14 variables. Perhaps this is a stupid question but will that slow down my site compared to the old way with using a single array (if 14 even is considered "big")? This is a common query that hopefully many users will use simultaniously and often. Prepared statements are new for me so..

Thanks sofar for the help people.

Comment: As long as you set the `$username` it's ok.

Comment: IMHO, session data should be treated as user input.

Comment: To expand on @feeela's comment, you should use prepared statements in order to avoid injection attacks. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into **prepared statements**. This is one of the many benefits of mysqli. It allows you to insert variables without having to worry about SQL injection. `mysqli_real_escape_string` will work most times, but prepared statements are the only truly secure method for avoiding attacks.

**Example from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, the insert querys are all done with prepared statements. My issue was conserning the fetching of data with a prepared select and then inserted into an array. That's why i had to use my "old" code since i found the array building very messy. 

Thank for the answer though.

Comment: Fair enough. I just thought I'd mention this; it never hurts to be extra paranoid when it comes to DB security.

Answer (score 1):

If the username is e.g. `Jean D'arc` the string reaching the mysql server would be

```
SELECT
  product_id, product_title, product_value
FROM
  product
WHERE
  user_id='Jean D'arc'
```

and that would result in a parse error.
Properly encoding/escaping the parameters *within* an sql statement is not only necessary for preventing malicious input from users but for every parameter where you can't (with absolute certainty) be sure it doesn't contain characters that may break the statement. In case of (any tiny) doubt encode/escape the parameter, or simply use prepared statements.

Comment: Well, the username is the one that the user entered during registration. That one has been prepared and will also get evaluated before inserting into the database to ensure that only accepted char's will be used. 

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Don't patronize the users. Use the approriate function/methods to get the data into your database - always!

Comment: Wouldn't a prepared statement help OP avoid this in the first place?

Comment: Matt: Yes, and there's doesn't seem to be a real reason not to use them.